# How to mock the get_object method of a Django Rest Framework view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mocking, factory-boy

I am playing with the `build` (as opposed to `create`) method of FactoryBoy in Django.  This creates objects without storing them in the database.

Therefore, in order for the tests of my views to work, I need to patch the methods that touch the database.

Here is some code...

**models.py:**

```
class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ('name')
```

**views.py:**

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Book.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
         return BookSerializer
```

**tests.py:**

```
class BookFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
  title = factory.Faker('sentence', nb_words=4)
  class Meta:
    model = "Book"

def my_test():
  client = APIClient()
  books = BookFactory.build_batch(10)
  list_url = reverse("books-list")
  with patch.object(BookViewSet, "get_queryset", return_value=books):
    list_url = reverse("books-list")
    response = client.get(list_url)
    # this works
    assert response.content = <a list of books> 
  with patch.object(BookViewSet, "get_object", return_value=books[0]):
    detail_url = reverse("books-detail", args=123)
    response = client.get(detail_url)
    # this is always empty..
    assert response.content == <a book>
```

No matter what I try, the detail-view always returns empty JSON.  Am I using `patch` wrong?

Comment: Why are you not using the method [mentioned here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#example) ?

Comment: If you are sure that books are indeed built, you can try patching it like this: patch('views.BookViewSet. get_queryset').

Comment: @bdbd - Thanks.  The issue I had discovered is that the `get_queryset` method of `BookViewSet` has been overridden and includes some calls that require querysets (not lists), like `prefetch_related`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when retrieving a list (when get_queryset is used). Instead of passing a list, you should pass a queryset as return_value.

```
books = BookFactory.build_batch(2)
queryset = MockSet(books[0], books[1])
queryset.model = Book  # fix django-filter issue " TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class"
with patch.object(BookViewSet, "get_queryset", return_value=queryset):
    # do your stuff here
```